# Android gradle problem while build with using MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, gradle, mpandroidchart

I am trying to use MPAndroidChart, but there is occuring build gradle problem.

I reference the github document below.

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

I follow the 'Gradle Setup'

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
}
```

This is how I put the codes

[image]

and when I started to build it the error code is
`Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven' was added by build file 'app\build.gradle'`

Did I put the build code in the wrong way? or did I missed some important settings?

Comment: Which version of gradle are you using?

Comment: maybe just remove the maven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you need to append the entry, `maven { ... }` to the `dependencyResolutionManagement.repositories` clause in `settings.gradle`.

**app/build.gradle**

```
// repositories {
//    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
// }
```

**settings.gradle**

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } 
    }
}
```